# HTTP ERROR: 404 in accessing to kura web ui

Tags: java, web, iot, kura

I cant access to **kura** web UI. It gives me **HTTP ERROR: 404** error.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you have installed Kura without web ui. (happened to me more than once)

In [official download page](https://www.eclipse.org/kura/downloads.php) look at the right column *Kura 1.3.0 Extended Downloads*, the description says

> The below downloads contain the Kura Web UI, [...] These features, while released under Eclipse Public License, depend on third party libraries that cannot be distributed directly by Eclipse.

Download your required version (and Developer Workspace) from the right column and reinstall Kura **with** web ui.

If you already have the version with web ui, posting your `/var/log/kura.log` and `/var/log/kura-console.log` might help finding the error.